# WordPress search input field not styling correctly

Tags: css, search, forms, input, twitter-bootstrap

I have a WordPress website that's using the Twitter Bootstrap framework.  Here's the website: http://www.vickieats.com/

I'm trying to style the search form for a website very similar to the search form that they use in their example page (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms).  However, the search button winds up being much bigger in height than the input element, and my goal is to make them the same height.

I think there's an CSS style that's overriding what I'm trying to do, but I've used FireBug to death and can't find the answer.  Or it could be something very simple that I'm overlooking.

Either way, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the end of your stylesheet (section or file)

```
input.search-query {
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

When adding this in Chrome Inspector the search box is aligned with the button. It doesn't matter that you already have declared input.search-query. It seems that you really could clean up in the CSS, though, `padding-right` defined more than once, and so on.

Partly screenshot of the result http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2lmtnht&s=6

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing it from `type="search"` to `type="text"`? My guess is that search is not customizable, while text is.

Answer (score 0):

Line-height prevents a simple "height" declaration from changing the size of the button. I was able to use the following to resize the button:

```
.form-search .input-append .btn {
line-height: 10px;
}
```

The issue is this makes things quite small, i'd consider making the input bigger to match the button for usability.

Hope that helps,

Nick

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure which way round you wanted it to change, so here's both.

Remove '`padding: 4px 14px;`' and '`line-height: 20px;`' from the `.btn` class in the bootstrap CSS to make the button as small as the input field.

To make the input field larger to match the button instead, remove `'height: 20px;'` from this massive selector in the bootstrap css:

`'select, textarea, input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="datetime"], input[type="datetime-local"], input[type="date"], input[type="month"], input[type="time"], input[type="week"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="url"], input[type="search"], input[type="tel"], input[type="color"], .uneditable-input'`

Comment: It is an extremely bad idea to edit the bootstrap.css file. If it is nessecary to change the basic styling, just overwrite the CSS classses in a local `<style>` -section.

Comment: It's only really a bad idea if you think it is. Subjective really. What if you kept track of your edits externally somehow so you could reapply them after updates? Or what if you never plan to update Bootstrap at all?

Making your edits in a local style section, or overriding them elsewhere isn't a guarantee that they won't break later, or of anything else really.

Comment: Thanks Tyler for your answer.  However, I did want to avoid editing the bootstrap.css file if at all possible.